# mysql_query() is FALSE but mysql_error() is blank

Tags: php, mysql, mysql5

I'm running pretty complicated query that is built from a few inner queries. The query contained SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS at the beginning of it. Unfortunately only number of rows could be fetched (I couldn't fetch result itself).

I decided to get rid of SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and run two different queries, one that counts rows and second that fetches them. In this case I can retrieve results but COUNT(*) query acts strangely. This is what I do:

1. Perform COUNT(*) query
2. mysql_query() returns FALSE
3. mysql_error() run directly after the COUNT(*) query returns blank string

The code is:

```
$sqlCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM ... WHERE ...";
$resultCount = mysql_query($sqlCount);
echo "RESULT COUNT: " . ($resultCount === FALSE) . "<br />";//it returns 1(true)
echo mysql_error(); //it returns nothing (blank string)
```

**ADDITIONALLY mysql_errno() returns 0**

Could you find any reasonable explanation of such a strange situation?

Comment: Please post the code to help you more appropriately.

Comment: Please show us some actual PHP code.

Comment: $resultCount=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sqlCount)); echo "RESULT COUNT: " . $resultCount[0];

Comment: Are you using `mysql_connect` first?

Comment: $resultCount doesn't hold number of records your query found, it's a resource created by mysql_query() that you have to traverse trough. On the other hand, I'd suggest switching to PDO seeing that mysql_* functions are obsolete now.

Comment: instead of $resultCount === FALSE try using $resultCount == FALSE

Comment: @fsonmezay - mysql_query is FALSE meaning that something went wrong and no results will be returned so your later code doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: @tandu - sure. That's not a case

Comment: @N.B - yes, I know. It's used to show that the query was incorrect (=== FALSE).

Comment: Have you enabled full error reporting? Many PHP functions tend to throw warnings when error conditions are met and they often provide information that cannot be gathered anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any mistakes in your code. Please try to change your mysql_query line to

```
 $resultCount = mysql_query($sqlCount) or die(mysql_error() ." <-- There was an error when proccessing query");
```

It looks weird but could help you

Answer (score 0):

It's strange because select clause with SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS returns rows and additional query will return number of rows. If you use

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from table');
$total = mysql_query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()');
process $result.
```

you shouldn't get any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please fill out the ...gaps and try

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$mysql = mysql_query('..', '..', '..') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('...', $mysql) or die(mysql_error($mysql));

echo '<pre>Debug: mysql_get_server_info='; var_dump(mysql_get_server_info($mysql)); echo "</pre>\n";
echo '<pre>Debug: mysql_get_client_info='; var_dump(mysql_get_client_info()); echo "</pre>\n";

$sqlCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS c FROM ... WHERE ...";
echo '<pre>Debug: sqlCount='; var_dump($sqlCount); echo "</pre>\n";
$resultCount = mysql_query($sqlCount, $mysql);
echo '<pre>Debug: resultCount='; var_dump($resultCount); echo "</pre>\n";
echo '<pre>Debug: mysql_error='; var_dump(mysql_error($mysql)); echo "</pre>\n";
echo '<pre>Debug: mysql_errno='; var_dump(mysql_errno($mysql)); echo "</pre>\n";
```

and post the output?